# eggPlant installation on RedHat7: Library Errors

Tags: redhat, eggplant

I installed the eggPlant15.20.rpm on our Linux/RedHat7 system, however seem not to take its license properly, causing it not launch at all. 
 I was wondering if the eggPlant RedHat installation is not sufficient, and whether we need other dependencies.

When running efls command to launch the License Panel, I see the below library messages: 
 [root@RHEL-BLD1 Library]# efls 
 /usr/GNUstep/System/Tools/gpbs: /usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries/libjpeg.so.62: no version information available (required by /usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries/libgnustep-gui.so.0.23) 
 /usr/GNUstep/System/Tools/gpbs: /usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries/libjpeg.so.62: no version information available (required by /lib/libtiff.so.3) 
 [root@RHEL-BLD1 Library]#

Googling the above libraries does not provide much help.

Anybody knows the cause of the above problems?